# Trouble with foreign key and inserting record with EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following classes:

```
public class Instrument
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Book { get; set; }
    public string Page { get; set; }
}
public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string OrderName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<MatchedInstrument> MatchedInstruments { get; set; }
}
public class MatchedInstrument
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //public int InstrumentId { get; set; }
    public Instrument Instrument { get; set; }
    public bool IsIncluded { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
}
```

And the following EF DbContext:

```
    public class AppContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Instrument> Instruments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Order>().HasKey(o => o.Id)
           .HasMany(o => o.MatchedInstruments)
           .WithMany().Map(m => 
           {
              m.MapLeftKey("orderid");
              m.MapRightKey("selectedmatchid");
              m.ToTable("ordermatchedinstruments");
           });

        modelBuilder.Entity<MatchedInstrument>().HasKey(m => m.Id)
           .HasRequired(m => m.Instrument)
           .WithRequiredPrincipal();
   }
}
```

Note that the **OrderMatchedInstruments** table is a join table that simply contains two columns: orderid and matchedinstrumentid (relating to the **MatchedInstruments** table).  The schema for the **MatchedInstruments** table looks like this:

```
[dbo].[MatchedInstruments](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [IsIncluded] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Notes] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [InstrumentId] [int] NOT NULL
```

This all seems to work fine for querying data.  I am able to query an order and include its matched instruments.

However, **when I try to add a new MatchedInstrument to an order, I get an error telling me that InstrumentId cannot be null in the MatchedInstrument table.**

```
...
// Demo Code - count on non-null objects
var instrument = _context.Instruments.FirstOrDefault(); 
var order = _context.Orders.SingleOrDefault(o => o.Id == 5);
order.MatchedInstruments.Add(new MatchedInstrument() { Instrument = instrument });
_context.SaveChanges();
```

This leads me to think I need to add an InstrumentId property to the MatchedInstrument class.  However, I thought that EF worked fine without having the foreign key as long as it held to the appropriate naming conventions.  IOW, the fact that I have navigation property of Instrument would lead me to think that it would automatically look in the table for InstrumentId and would therefore populate that for me.

Is this not the case or am I missing something in regards with how EF deals with foreign keys?

Comment: Can you please show how do you add MatchedInstrument to and order?. do you create a "new instance" or pull existing from DB and add to the collection?

Comment: Why does your model `MatchedInstrument` not match the table?  `IsFavorite` is not `IsIncluded`.  Also how did the `Id` on `MatchedInstruments` become an `IDENTITY(1,1)` when there does not appear to be any fluent nor attributes that specify that `id` is DbGenerated (probably the problem, EF doesn't know how to get the ID from the DB since it's not specified it comes from the DB)?

Comment: Sorry, IsFavorite/IsIncluded was a typo.  They are the same, I've corrected my code above.  Hmm, I've done this many times before on simple tables and never had to tell EF that I was working with IDENTITY fields in the DB.  However, maybe I've just been lucky to this point and this is one case where it becomes necessary?

Comment: For example, the ID in orders is also IDENTITY.  I have nothing in my EF configuration to indicate this.  However, when I add an order in code and SaveChanges(), the order is added and an Id is generated by the database.

Comment: Could it be that you just create a new instance of MatchedInstrument with Instrument property = null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got this to work.  I had set up my relationship incorrectly in my mapping.  I changed from using WithRequiredPrincipal to the following:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<MatchedInstrument>().HasKey(m => m.Id)
       .HasRequired(m => m.Instrument)
       .WithMany().HasForeignKey(m => m.InstrumentId);
```

Not sure why I thought I needed to use WithRequiredPrincipal(), but that definitely fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following attribute to each of your ID properties in your models:

```
[Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
```

Comment: Mike, I'm not disagreeing that the DatabaseGenerated option needs to be added.  I'm curious though why I'm able to save an Order without that attribute.  (See my comment above to Erik.)

Answer (score -1):

As I see you are not sending the InstrumentId, but the object Instrument, this is the cause of your problem, because you schema has InstrumentId as a Not Null Integer and what you are sending is the entire Instrument Object, you just need to be sure of what data you really need and then change your code.

Grettings...Ing. Jorge Pérez Bárcenas